# Simple HTML DOM parsing isnt functioning

Tags: php, html, parsing, sourceforge

I am trying to learn HTML DOM parsing at my localhost. But I crash right in the beggining.

1. I have made a new project
2. I have downloaded files from [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html)

3. I have put this code inside my HTML project
4. I get this error, when I run the script:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 15

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You need to use DOM parser. Details [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

Comment: @AshiqurRahman I have downloaded those files and have them in my project folder

Comment: You need to include the DOM parser PHP library file in your HTML code.

Comment: you have to download and include php  dom parser  `https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PHP DOM Parser Library No Longer Support to **PHP latest Version** so, You Need to Use cURL for that It will help you.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.co.in");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $result;
?>
```

Try this..!

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_html` does not belong to `php`.

To use it you need to download and include [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/).

Then you can use it like this

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the DOM parser PHP library file in your HTML code using PHP include function.

```
<html>
    <head>       
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
           include_once('domparser.php');// use your file location 
        // put your code here
         $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```